# MPAndroidChart PieChart how to change the center text to display the different color and sizes

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

        SpannableString str1= new SpannableString("Last \n 1 Days ");
        str1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, str1.length(), 0);
        builder.append(str1);

        SpannableString str2= new SpannableString("View Detail");
        str2.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, str2.length(), 0);
        builder.append(str2);

        pieChart.setCenterText(""+builder);
```

I used here MPAndroidChart library for PieChart implementation.I want to change my center text in pie chart with different colors with different sizes.But using SpannableString it is not set color...plz suggest solution.

Answer (score 3):

Please use following code:

```
String str1 = "Last \n 1 Days ";
String str2 = "View Detail";

SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(str1 + str2);
ForegroundColorSpan fcs1 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
ForegroundColorSpan fcs2 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN);
sb.setSpan(fcs1, 0, str1.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
sb.setSpan(fcs2, str1.length(), str1.length() + str2.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

piechart.setCenterText(sb);
```

Answer (score 2):

SpannableString won't be a good solution while using the MPAndroidChart library.

[You can refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32420597/4758329) to format your text at the center of a pie chart.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is helped me a lot.